# How to access fields inside MongoDB document in Apache NiFi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

In my NiFi workflow,I  configured a **getMongo** Processor along with query property .

**my query is working fine** and I am getting back the response from MongoDB in Ni-Fi as shown below

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5dcadc91f027705b1834d6c5" }, "empId" : "333-44-6J", "accountId" : "444434D2", "fulltimeEmployee" : "true", "DateJoined" : "07/14/2016 11:37:42", "Bloddgroup" : "null" }
```

I want to route **DateJoined,Bloodgroup** etc fields for further processing.

**How do I access these fields** once we have the response available in **getMongo** processor.

I tired to use Processors like **RouteonAttribute** and **UpdateAttribute** and trying to access **DateJoined**  using **"${DateJoined}"** .but I am getting null value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) and configure dynamic property `DateJoined` set as `$.DateJoined` and `Bloodgroup` set as `$.Bloodgroup`. This will extract these json properties into FlowFile attributes and will allow you to address them as you did using expression language(`${Bloodgroup}` and `${DateJoined}`)

Answer (score 1):

Only attributes can be accessed using $ Symbol, since DB records are not attributes, you need to use **EvaluateJsonPath** processor as Ben mentioned and then fetch the attributes using **${DateJoined}**